# California car insurance for rental cars?

Tags: usa, california, car-insurance

California seems to be one of few states (other significant one being Texas), where rental companies [are not obliged to provide option of mandatory liability insurance](http://www.best-car-rental-tips.com/liability-insurance.html) and do not include the basic coverage in the cost of rental. They seem to provide that as an extra, charging ridiculous amounts if you take it directly from them ($15-$20 per day).

So what are are the alternatives in California, if one is looking to either rent a car for longer period or frequently rent cars?

*Update:* Regarding existing insurance, I'm a recent expat and I do not yet own car in US, thus I don't have any US car insurance.

Comment: Do you have an existing car insurance policy for some other car? That might cover a rental car if your usual car isn't appropriate for the purpose (ie. carrying more people than the capacity of your usual car).

Comment: I've never seen insurance included in the rental price in the US, and I've rented cars in several states--but never TX or CA.

Comment: @Flimzy: note, that I'm talking about basic, obligatory *liability insurance*, not optional *additional/supplement liability insurance*. In other words it's kind of insurance, without which you cannot legally drive a car.

Comment: @vartec: Yes, that's what I'm talking about, too. In my experience, rental companies do everything they can to make their price appear as low as possible, including omitting "obligatory" insurances like that. Although, if you drive without such insurance, to my knowledge, you are liable, not the company. Also, most private insurance policies cover rentals, so few people actually need insurance from the rental companies anyway.

Comment: @Flimzy: http://www.best-car-rental-tips.com/liability-insurance.html claims that CA and TX are the only exceptions

Comment: You may be interested in [non-owner insurance](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/35859/444).

Comment: You may also be interested in short-term rental companies such as http://zipcar.com/, where everything is included for a flat rate.

Comment: @vartec: it claims they are "common" exceptions, I don't see it saying they are the only exceptions.

Comment: @Flimzy Fair enough. Lets just leave it at that, as it isn't relevant to the core of the question.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Yeah, I know there are few like that. But I actually want to rent or lease a car for month or more.

Answer (score 2):

According to California DMV, The following minimum liability insurance is required for private passenger vehicles:

$15,000 for injury/death to one person. (Also known as bodily injury liability)
$30,000 for injury/death to more than one person.
$5,000 for damage to property. (Also known as product damage liability)
Third party liability insurance compensates a person other than the driver for personal injury or property damage. Comprehensive or collision insurance does not meet vehicle financial responsibility requirements. It covers the situation where you hit and break someone's leg (bodily injury) or run over someone's fence (property damage).

The only required insurance coverage when renting cars in California is third party liability. Of course, many people choose to get insurance over and above what is legally required. Drivers must also carry proof of liability insurance (your own insurance card or the car rental contract if liability coverage was purchased) as that is required by law.
for more information visit our website: [Tyres Warrington](http://breakdownrecoverywarrington.com/tyres-warrington/)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Geico website](https://www.geico.com/information/aboutinsurance/auto/insights/car-rentals/):

> If you don't own a car but still need affordable car rental insurance, ask your GEICO representative about a non-owner liability policy and/or personal effects coverage available on your homeowners policy or renters insurance policy. Non-owner liability coverage may provide liability protection when you rent or borrow a car while personal effects coverage can make sure your possessions are covered away from home.

My guess is there is nothing special about Geico and many of the major US insurance companies will probably provide similar services.

Comment: I've contacted GEICO, they do not offer that. At least not in California. Their response *"Unfortunately, GEICO does not offer 3rd party liability for rental vehicles. I wish I could refer you to a company that offers this type of coverage but I am not aware of any."*

Comment: @vartec Hmmm, sometimes the web lies.

Comment: Well maybe not exactly *"lies"*, I think it was actually true at one point, not the case anymore.