# Liability insurance for frequent car rentals

Tags: usa, car-insurance

I have currently moved to Ohio, US. I was planning to start renting cars month on month since my company would be reimbursing it. But they refused to reimburse for insurance. So I have to pay the CDW and Liability Protection from my own pocket. My Credit card covers CDW but I am losing my brains over what to do with liability protection. 
I have started inquiring about non owner auto policy, but GEICO refused me cover since I am renting cars too frequently and for long duration. I would be calling up other insurance providers and check. Should I remain hopeful? If I have to pay $300-400 for liability every month, It would be better to buy or lease a car isn't it?

Comment: Please rephrase this in the form of a question that can be answered - the two questions in here are "should I remain hopeful?" and "would it be better to buy or lease a car?". These are very broad questions ...

Answer (score 1):

I've been in similar situation, I've talked with GEICO and Progressive as suggested in answer to this question: «[California car insurance for rental cars?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/3096/california-car-insurance-for-rental-cars)»

Unfortunately, what I have learned is that you cannot get their insurance unless you own a car. Once you have insurance for your own car, it does cover rentals to some extent. But it's not possible to get an insurance that would cover *only* rental cars.